# Selecting row even when count value is 0 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select c.id, count(*) as 'Transactions' from voucher v 
right join consumer c on v.consumer_id = c.id
where v.voucher_state in ('REDEEMED', 'EXPIRED') and c.country = 'INDIA'
group by c.id;
```

**Expected output :-**

Id     Transactions

3     0

4     0

6     3

7     9

8     4

9     0

**Current output :-**

Id     Transactions

6     3

7     9

8     4

How do I select the rows who has count = 0? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `LEFT JOIN`, place `consumer` table on the left side and move

```
 v.voucher_state in ('REDEEMED', 'EXPIRED'):
```

to `ON` clause:

```
select c.id, count(v.consumer_id) as 'Transactions' 
from consumer c
left join voucher v  on v.consumer_id = c.id on v.voucher_state in ('REDEEMED', 'EXPIRED')
where c.country = 'INDIA'
group by c.id;
```

The above query will return *all* `customer.id` values satisfying condition

```
customer.country = 'INDIA'
```

Only customers having a matching record in `voucher` table with

```
voucher.voucher_state in ('REDEEMED', 'EXPIRED')
```

will be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `RIGHT JOIN`, the filtering condition on the left table must be in the `ON` clause. The reason is, the filtering will happen before the optimizer join it with the right table. The `WHERE` clause will filter in the final result.

Another thing, you must count only the rows in the left table (eg. `COUNT(v.consumer_id))`) rather than `COUNT(*)`, otherwise, there will always be one count for each `c.id`.

```
select c.id, count(v.consumer_id) as 'Transactions' 
from voucher v 
     right join consumer c 
       on v.consumer_id = c.id 
          and v.voucher_state in ('REDEEMED', 'EXPIRED')
where  c.country = 'INDIA'
group  by c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `IFNULL`

```
select c.id,IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) as 'Transactions' from voucher v 
right join consumer c on v.consumer_id = c.id
where v.voucher_state in ('REDEEMED', 'EXPIRED') and c.country = 'INDIA'
group by c.id;
```